# Normals set in the Z axis, but Solidify only operating in Y axis?

Tags: solidify-modifier

Basically I am having difficulty making the solidify function work correctly. I have modelled this spoon and am attempting to thicken it, however when I do the solidify happens in the Y axis, even though, as can be seen from the screenshot below, the normals are clearly in the Z axis. How do I fix this? I dont see anyone online who has this issue. I have already flipped normals etc makes no sense to my why its doing this. Please help!

Aaron

[image: Normals clearly shown]

[image]

Comment: Hello. It seems your model suffers from a classic case of non-uniform scale. Dare I say it is even an outlier in this peculiar disease. Not only is this model non-uniformly scaled, it is scaled negatively ! Luckily, next time one of your models suffers from such illness you won't have to look too far on your screen, the solution was just [under your nose](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wrLLB.png). To cure the illness, the 3D doctor prescribes selecting your model in object mode, then going Object > Align > Scale or CTRL + A > Scale if you prefer shortcuts to plain old menu exploration. Cheers

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfect